# How to know that all attachments in Corda transaction have been received

Tags: attachment, corda

When a sender node run a transaction with a receiver node, is there a way for the receiver to know that all attachments are stored in the receiver vault ?

Responder ?

Answer (score 2):

Corda takes care of storing all the attachments for you, so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

That being said, you could add some logic to check the node's attachment storage for the attachments. But, that is going to require sending some information around so that counterparties know what attachments were meant to be stored.